# XMLHttpRequest: How to force caching?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, xmlhttprequest

I'm newer to XMLHttpRequests since I've previously used jQuery's AjAX method. However I need to work in a web worker and now I have to use the classic XMLHttpRequest for performance issues.

I'm trying to rebuild the `cache`-property from jquery. If cache should be disabled I add this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

But what header should I set if I want to force caching (not prevent)?

Comment: @idbehold — That would do the opposite of what is being asked for.

Comment: Also I don't like this method since my routes (e.g. if route == someroute/) would be invalid with timestamp-parameters

Comment: Oh, duh! Sorry, ignore me.

Comment: If you really want to force client-side caching, you should abstract out the XHRs (behind a model or library) and implement the caching within that.

Comment: So there is nothing to enforce caching? Will jQuery also do nothing?

Comment: If you do not want to fetch the content over and over, why don't you store a local copy and use it?

Comment: What is the best way to >disable< caching? I'm not asking about the query-string timestamp solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a variety of headers you can set to encourage caching, but they (including `Cache-Control` which you are using incorrectly) are **response** headers that must be sent by the server and not request headers.

One such example of using Cache-Control:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
```

This [Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) covers them in more depth.

Comment: Ok so there is nothing I can do to enforce caching with JS?

Comment: @user3631654 — Not at the HTTP level. You could copy the data to local storage and then get it from there instead of the server.

Comment: Ok that's an idea. But one more question: Will jQuery also do nothing to enforce caching?

Comment: All the standard caching rules are implemented by the browser, jQuery doesn't do anything about that because browsers already handle it.

Comment: But it will have a method to prevent from caching. I am not understand why the prefered way of doing it is to append a query string with a timestamp. On many applications (including mine) this will not work since all the routes will not determine routes with get-params

Comment: Um, adding a random querysting value *will* force the browser to not read the cached version. Not sure how you think that it would not.

Comment: `Cache-Control` *can* be used as a request header, and it supports `no-cache`, as stated by [RFC 7234](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.1).

Comment: @FranklinYu It can be used as a request header, but all it does is pass that header along to an actual `cache` (if you have one).  Per RFC: _The "Cache-Control" header field is used to specify directives for caches along the request/response chain._

Comment: @Orwellophile That is true. Meanwhile, the browser itself is also considered part of the chain (AFAIK), so it will see the request header and attempt to cache it.

Comment: @FranklinYu Chrome does appear to honor `cache-control: no-cache` during requests, one can only hope `cache-control: max-stale` would do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 7):

You can specify `max-stale` without an argument, in `Cache-Control` header of your *request*. From [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.2):

> The `max-stale` request directive indicates that the client is willing to accept a response that has exceeded its freshness lifetime.  If `max-stale` is assigned a value, then the client is willing to accept a response that has exceeded its freshness lifetime by no more than the specified number of seconds.  If no value is assigned to `max-stale`, then the client is willing to accept a stale response of any age.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Caching static assets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#caching_static_assets)

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800, immutable
```