# How to cache XMLHttpRequest response in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, templates, caching

I have a function that loads my html templates asynchronously:

```
loadTplAsync: function(path) {

        return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", path, true);
            xhr.onload = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        resolve(_.template(xhr.responseText));
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.onerror = error => reject(error);
            xhr.send(null);
        });
    }
```

How to extend this function to cache responses by browser?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154796/xmlhttprequest-how-to-force-caching#answer-28154871

Comment: Have you tried using `ServiceWorker`, [Cache](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#cache) API?

Comment: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that what you mean by cache is not to repeat making same request during life cycle of that page load you could store the promise as a variable and return the same promise each time.

The first time a specific  path is requested will make a new request, subsequent times only the stored promise will be returned

```
var promises ={};
loadTplAsync: function(path) {
        // create new promise if it doesn't already exist for path instance
        if(!promises[path]){
          promises[path] = Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", path, true);
            xhr.onload = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        resolve(_.template(xhr.responseText));
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.onerror = error => reject(error);
            xhr.send(null);
        });
      }
      // return the stored promise
      return promises[path];
    }
```

Note this is not a persistent cache and new requests would be made on subsequent page loads

Comment: How to do the persistent cache ?