# How to print all character names from Game of thrones Api which is in paginated form | Traverse paginated API in JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

Hello, i am trying to make a side project using game of thrones API. Out of curiosity, I want to print all the characters name from https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters .

From the response headers and documentation (https://anapioficeandfire.com/Documentation#pagination), I see this Api has 214 pages.
How do i fetch the character names from all of these 214 pages.

My Current attempt allows me to get names from only 1st 10 objects

Here is my attempt :

```js
(function() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(req.getResponseHeader("link"));
      let charObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      for (let i = 0; i < charObj.length; i++) {
        let p = document.createElement("p");
        let name = document.createTextNode(charObj[i].name);
        p.appendChild(name);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    }
  };
  req.open("GET", "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters", true);
  req.send();
})();
```

Comment: I have tried to be specific with the question. Why has it been downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).  There is a `link` Header property that tells you the `next`, `prev`, and `last` URLs of the endpoint you are looking at.

You should chain/sequence requests in such a way that you fetch the first URL, get the `next` URL, and make a call to the next page.  Keep doing this until you run out of pages and collect all the characters that way.

I noticed that not everyone has a `name`, so I pull either the name or the first alias.

Also, to ease the access to the server, I limited the depth of the process to 3 requests.  You should remove that if you don't want the limit.

```js
function parseHeaders(res) {
    return res.headers.get("link").split(",").reduce((acc, link) => {
        const props = /^\<(.+)\>; rel="(.+)"$/.exec(link.trim());
        if (!props) {
            console.warn("no match");
            return acc;
        }
        acc[props[2]] = props[1];
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

async function go(url, depth = 0) {
    /*
     * You don't need this, this is just to alleviate load on the API's server
     * You should remove all the stuff about depth whenever you use this,
     * it just limits the total number of requests to fire to 3 which is nice
     * since it looks like there would be like 215 requests if you didn't do this.
     */
    if (depth >= 3) return [];

    const res = await fetch(url);
    const props = parseHeaders(res);
    const data = await res.json();
    const characters = data.map(character => character.name || character.aliases[0]);

    if (props.next) {
        const newCharacters = await go(props.next, depth + 1);
        characters.push(...newCharacters);
    }

    return characters;
}

(async function() {
    const characters = await go("https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters");
    console.log(characters);
}());
```

Comment: Any idea on how to cache this request instead of using depth? As you can see 214 requests are fired with this code. (Since there are 214 pages)

Comment: @SiddharthJain Define cache.  Your browser should be caching these requests since they are GETs.  Either way, caching this action could be an entirely different question.

Comment: Here is the link to the other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329431/how-to-implement-caching-game-of-thrones-api

Feel free to post your thoughts!

Answer (score 4):

In the [Documentation](https://anapioficeandfire.com/Documentation#pagination), you can see that you can specify the `page number` and the `pageSize`, however :

> 3. You can specify how many items you want to receive per page, the maximum is 50

By adding those parameters at the end of your `url` you can get a maximum of 50 items per page, add `page=1&pageSize=50` ( since the original page size is `10` )

But you can put your request in a loop to fetch all the pages from `1` to `214`, `10` at a time :

( loose the IFEE and call the function in a for loop )

```js
function getItems(page) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //console.log(req.getResponseHeader("link"));
      let charObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      for (let i = 0; i < charObj.length; i++) {
        let p = document.createElement("p");
        let name = document.createTextNode(charObj[i].name);
        p.appendChild(name);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    }
  };
  req.open("GET", "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters?page=" + page + "&pageSize=10", true);
  req.send();
};

for (let i = 1; i <= 214; i++) {
  getItems(i)
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to cache this request?  As you can see 214 requests are fired with this code. (Since there are 214 pages)

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154796/xmlhttprequest-how-to-force-caching