# How to implement caching || Game of thrones API

Tags: javascript, caching

I am playing around with Game of thrones Api - https://anapioficeandfire.com/Documentation.

The documentation mentions they are implementing rate limiting. Hence implementing cache is important.

Let's say I want to print all the names of the houses from the Api on a button click

```
 function getAllHouseNames() {
   for (let i = 1; i <= 45; i++) {
     getHouseNames(i)
    }
  }

async function getHouseNames(page) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.onreadystatechange = await
  function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //console.log(req.getResponseHeader("link"));
      let houseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      for (let i = 0; i < houseObj.length; i++) {
        let p = document.createElement("p");
        let name = document.createTextNode(houseObj[i].name);
        p.appendChild(name);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    }
  };
  req.open("GET", "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses?page=" + page + "&pageSize=10", true);
  req.send();
};
```

Around 45 requests are fired (Since there are 45 pages with information about houses).

How do i implement caching technique in this scenario?

Comment: You can't `await` a function. Did you mean to construct a `new Promise` around your XHR?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, thats what i am trying to do. Also, how do i go about implementing a caching technique so that 45 requests aren't fired everytime user clicks the button which triggers - getAllHouseNames function

Comment: [Caching is rather trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18745499/1048572) with promises, but first you need to make your function properly return a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global/module level variable. In the code below, I called it cache. then add the properties to it when you have retrieved them. then they are available for later use.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>A Song of Ice and Fire</title>
<!-- include jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var cache = {}; // create a new object for the cache
$(document).ready(function() {
    // once the page is loaded, register a click listener on the button
    $("#btn-get-house-names").on("click", getAllHouseNames);
});

function getAllHouseNames() {
    // if the cache object doesn't have 
    // a property called "houseNames", go ajax
    // otherwise just display the house names in the document
    if (!cache.houseNames) {
        $("#div-house-names").html("Getting House Names");
        getHouseNamesAjax()
    } else {
        $("#div-house-names").html("");
        $.each(cache.houseNames, function(index, houseName) {
            $("#div-house-names").append("<p>" + houseName + "</p>");
        });
    }
}

function getHouseNamesAjax(page) { // use jQuery to ajax
    let pageId = "";
    let pageSize = "pageSize=10";
    if (page) {
        pageId = "?page=" + page + "&" + pageSize;
    } else {
        pageId = "?" + pageSize;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses" + pageId,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
            if (!cache.houseNames) { // add the houseNames array to the cache object
                cache.houseNames = [];
            }
            $.each(data, function(index, house) {
                cache.houseNames.push(house.name); // append to the end of the array
            });
            if (request.getResponseHeader("link")) { // this looks to see if there is another page of house names
                let headerLinks = request.getResponseHeader("link").split(",");
                let hasNext = false;
                $.each(headerLinks, function(index, headerLink) {
                    let roughLink = headerLink.split("; ")[0];
                    let roughRel = headerLink.split("; ")[1];
                    let rel = roughRel.substring(5, roughRel.length - 1);
                    if (rel == "next") {
                        let pageNum = roughLink.split("?page=")[1].split("&page")[0];
                        getHouseNamesAjax(pageNum);
                        hasNext = true;
                        return false; // break out of $.each()
                    }
                });
                if (!hasNext) { 
                    // if no more pages of houseNames, 
                    // display the house names on the page.
                    // We have to do this here, because ajax is async
                    // so the first call didn't display anything.
                    getAllHouseNames();
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, request) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="btn-get-house-names" value="Get House Names"/>
<div id="div-house-names"> <!-- house names -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```